# How can I draw a timeline using tikz with itemize/enumerate function (graphical example attached)

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize, timeline

How can I draw a timeline using tikz like below?

[image]

I attempted with my own code but I was not able to itemize/enumerate, and the formatting looks like a mess.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=4.5cm]
\draw[black,->,thick,>=latex]
  (0,0) -- (4,0) node[below right] {$\scriptstyle t$};
\foreach \Xc in {0,...,3}
{
  \draw[black,thick] 
    (\Xc,0) -- ++(0,5pt) node[above] {$\scriptstyle \Xc$};
}
\node[below,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt,color=black] 
  at (0,0) 
  {Nature determines the state of the economy.};  
\node[below,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
  at (1,0) 
  {Trading occurs};  
\node[below,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
  at (2,0) 
  {The manager of each firm privately observes its entry cost};  
\node[below,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
  at (3,0) 
  {Firms are liquidated.};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This can easily be done in `tikz`. Any own attempts?

Comment: I've added some code of my own attempt. But everything seems a mess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some key points of your question:

- `\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}` makes your `tikzpicture` more compact.
- Draw the arrow: Use `\draw [->] (<start point>) -- (<end point>);` You can change the arrow shape as you like. (I use `[-stealth]` in the example below.)
- Specify coordinates: `\coordinate (<name>) at (<x>,<y>);`
- Calculate coordinates: `\coordinate (<point1>) at ($(<point1>)+(<xshift>,<yshift>)$);`. The `$...$` here claims a temporaty calculation environment instead of a math formula.
- Text positioning: Use `[anchor=...]` options.
- Add `itemize` environment: Just put the them into the node as: `\node [...] at (...) {\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}};`.

---

Here is a working example, you can improve it with `foreach` grammar.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% draw arrow
\coordinate (start) at (-4,0);
\coordinate (end) at (26,0);
\draw [line width=2pt, -stealth] (start) -- (end);

% You can use `foreach` to improve the following codes
\coordinate (s0) at (1,0);
\coordinate (t0) at ($(s0)+(0,0.3)$);
\coordinate (s1) at (11,0);
\coordinate (t1) at ($(s1)+(0,0.3)$);
\coordinate (s2) at (21,0);
\coordinate (t2) at ($(s2)+(0,0.3)$);

% draw ticks
\draw [line width=2pt] (s0) -- (t0);
\node [anchor=south] at (t0.north) {$t=0$};

\draw [line width=2pt] (t1) -- (s1);
\node [anchor=south] at (t1.north) {$t=1$};

\draw [line width=2pt] (t2) -- (s2);
\node [anchor=south] at (t2.north) {$t=2$};

% add texts
\node [anchor=north, align=left, text width=9cm] at (s0.south) {
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
};

\node [anchor=north, align=left, text width=9cm] at (s1.south) {
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[3]
\item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}
};

\node [anchor=north, align=left, text width=9cm] at (s2.south) {
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[5]
\item \lipsum[6]
\end{itemize}
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

an alternative:

- using the `enumitem` package for lists in nodes
- node are positioned by using the `positioning` library
- time line is drawn from the left top corner of the first node to the right top corner of the last node
- time events are determined by the `foreach` loop

by this measure the document example's code is simpler, cleaner and shorter.

**edit:**
ups, now I see that I forgot to add the mwe :-(. now it is here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep, leftmargin=*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 0mm and 0.02\linewidth,
    box/.style = {inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                  text width=0.32\linewidth,
                  align=left, font=\small}
                    ]
\node (n1) [box]
        {   \begin{itemize}
        \item   The shareshoulders design compensation contract for the manager simultaneously.
            \end{itemize}
        };
\node (n2) [box, below right=of n1.north east]
        {   \begin{itemize}
        \item   The manager of each firm privately observes its entry cost;
        \item   The manager make entry decision simultaneously;
        \item   Trading and financial market occurs.
            \end{itemize}
        };
\node (n3) [box, below right=of n2.north east]
        {   \begin{itemize}
        \item   Entry cost and profits are realised;
        \item   Manager receive their compensation;
        \item   Firms are liquidated.
         \end{itemize}
         };
\draw[thick, -latex]    (n1.north west) -- (n3.north east);
\foreach \x [count=\xx from 1] in {0,1,2}
    \draw (n\xx.north) -- + (0,3mm) node[above] {$t=\x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines are indicate text borders)